# Javascript toFixed bug in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

my code is:

```
var m=0.00542;
alert(m.toFixed(3));  
alert(m.toFixed(2));
```

the expected result is :0.005 0.01

but in ie6,the result is :0.005 0.00

what can i do?

Comment: You fix it by ditching support for IE6. It's a piece of barfed-up-partially digested garbage.

Comment: `0.9.toFixed(0)` returns `0` in IE6. What application is so important that it needs to support IE6?

Comment: @MarcB +1 for 'praising' the one and the only - the great - the best - IE6. But, that's not the answer to the question.

Comment: @parth: ... which is why it's a comment?

Comment: nice answer...er, comment? hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE6 is broken. Not even Google supports it anymore. This particular issue in easily fixed though.

To patch `Number.toFixed()`, define

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(n) {
    var power = Math.pow(10, n);
    var fixed = (Math.round(this * power) / power).toString();
    if(n == 0) return fixed;
    if(fixed.indexOf('.') < 0) fixed += '.';
    var padding = n + 1 - (fixed.length - fixed.indexOf('.'));
    for(var i = 0; i < padding; i++) fixed += '0';
    return fixed;
};
```

Your code should generate the expected output now.

Comment: It does perform rounding. Enter the same code in modern browsers.

Comment: `0.95.toFixed(1)` returns `1.0` in IE6.

Comment: The implementation of `toFixed` is incorrect. It returns a number, while it has to be a string. `0..toFixed(2)` has to return `0.00`, not `0`.

Comment: @RobW: Not my day. I think it's correct now. Or did I miss something again?

Comment: Looks better. [The specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4.5) states that a [`RangeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError) has to be thrown for values outside the 0-20 range (implementations may vary). Another thing: I recommend to test whether the implementation is broken before overwriting it: `if (0.9.toFixed(0) !== '1') { Number.prototype.toFixed = ... }`.

Comment: buggy! var x = 7158.1787512824557779822;
console.log(x.toFixed(20));
console.log(x.toFixed3(20));

Comment: @4esn0k: Now do the same with `x = 7158.178751282456` and tell me which one is buggy.

Comment: @Dennis, (7158.178751282456).toFixed(20) should be "7158.17875128245577798225", your implementation is BUGGY; "7158.17875128245577798225" is closer to the double representation of the 7158.178751282456